# RubyOnRails Internal API Call Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a controller and trying to call an internal API.
Here is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    begin
      response = RestClient.get "http://localhost:3000/api/users"
      json_response = JSON.parse response

      @users = json_response.map { |i|
        user = User.new(i['id'])
        user.first_name = i['first_name']
        user.last_name = i['last_name']
        user.email = i['email']
        user.user_name = i['user_name']
        user
      }
      rescue Exception => exp
        render :html => "Something went wrong ! Try again later."
      end
    end
end
```

And this is the API

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    invoker = ProviderInvoker.new(UserProvider.new)
    data = invoker.getData
    byebug
    render json: data, adapter: :json
  end
end
```

Funny thing is, when I first call the API, it throws "Net::ReadTimeout" error but falls to my byebug in API right after the error(this happens in the same runtime, not in another call try). I see the error page then refresh the page (which means another API call) and everything works fine now. I see the data coming from the API. It doesn't work in the first time, but works in the second time.

If I go to "http://localhost:3000/api/users" via browser URL and see the json, API works even in the first try. It is like framework get the API working after the first call. What am I experiencing here ?

Comment: How does your local server structure look like? Are there two different applications or just one? How do you start your local servers? How many thread do you have running?

Comment: There is only one app. I start my local with "rails s". I wrote my app single thread but I see "Min threads: 5, max threads: 5" when I run the server if that's what you asking.

Comment: When it is just one app, why do you use HTTP to lad that data and why don't you just call the appropriate method directly?

Comment: It is a kind of code challenge, calling an internal API is one of the requirements